# How to recover the unallocated space while doing disk partitioning?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, and I partitioned my D drive and allocated 57GB for Ubuntu. But unfortunately, somehow the other partition in my D drive became unallocated like this

[image: My partitioned drives]]

I wanted to recover the unallocated space so I tried to create a new simple volume. But a message pops up before that.

[image: Message]

My question is if I agree and continue will it have any effect on Ubuntu that I have installed on D drive? And if it does, how do I recover the unallocated space?

Comment: Use alt+prnscr to print the current window instead of printing the whole screen and cut out like that. And be noted that Gb means Gigabit, to mean byte use GB.

Answer (score 1):

MBR is limited to [4 partitions per disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types), either *4 primary* or *3 primary + 1 extended* (where you can create more logical partitions inside). You already have 4 primary partitions on the drive, so you can't create more.

You must use some 3<sup>rd</sup> party partitioning tools (like [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html), [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html), [Macrorit Partition Expert](https://macrorit.com/partition-magic-manager/free-edition.html) or [fixparts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/)) to convert the E: drive to *logical* and then create a logical disk on the unallocated space.

See [How to change logical partition into primary one?](https://superuser.com/q/688239/241386)

---

You can also [convert from basic to dynamic disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks) (the Windows' equivalent to [LVM on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29)), which supports [1000 dynamic volumes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc737048(v%3Dws.10)). However that may cause issues later, because other partitioning tools may not work well with dynamic disk. Only use this option if you really know what dynamic disk is